# rails mysql2: how to verify mysql server's SSL certificate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, ssl-certificate, mysql2

I'm trying to connect remotely to a mysql db over SSL, with the server's certificate verified to match the DNS domain used to connect to the server.

Using the command-line `mysql` tool, I can make such a connection using `mysql --ssl-ca=/path/to/cacert.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert`.

Using rails mysql2, I set `sslca:`¹, which causes a not-fully-verified SSL connection like `mysql --ssl-ca=` does.  How do I do the equivalent of `--ssl-verify-server-cert` so that the connection fails if the server cert's domain is wrong?

I've tried adding the following which had no effect on this issue: `flags: SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT`, `flags: CLIENT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT`, `flags: 1073741824`, and `secure_auth: true`.

¹ either `sslca: /path/to/cacert.pem` in config/database.yml, or `?sslca=/path/to/cacert.pem` in a `mysql2://` URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not one of the default connection flags in the Mysql2 gem, but the constant is available and can be bitwise OR-ed into the connection flags field before making a connection.

You can set the global default like this:

```
Mysql2::Client::default_query_options[:connect_flags] |=
    Mysql2::Client::SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT
```

Or set the flags per connection:

```
client = Mysql2::Client.new(
    :connect_flags => (Mysql2::Client::default_query_options[:connect_flags]
                     | Mysql2::Client::SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT)
    )
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Using it with Rails (4.1), we set the global default in a new file config/initializers/ssl_verify_server_cert.rb and it is verifying correctly.  (Would a feature request or pull request be welcome to make it possible to specify this flag everywhere `sslca` can be specified?)

Answer (score 5):

With `mysql2>=0.4.0`, you can set `sslverify: true` and `sslca: path/to/cert_chain.pem` in your adapter configs to make the client verify the server identity.

Comment: The changelog says 0.4.0 is the first version to support `sslverify`. Nice. ( https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/releases )

Comment: Thanks for checking that for me, @idupree!